# ng-repeat items in fixed positions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat directive and I want to show different object values in fixed index positions.

data:

```
{
    "recipe": {
    "id":"0001",
    "name":"soup",
    "cat":[{"name":"dinner"}, {"name":"lunch"}, {"name":"breakfast"}]
}
```

I want it to show like..

ng-repeat:

> 1: (show cat.name: "breakfast") should only be shown at index 0
>
> 2: (dont show items that contains "breakfast", "dinner")
>
> 3: (dont show items that contains "breakfast") (show cat.name:
>   "dinner") - only show "dinner" at possition index 3
>
> 4: (dont show items that contains "breakfast", "dinner")
>
> 5: (dont show items that contains "breakfast", "dinner")

etc..

How should I manage this?

Comment: write custom filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`orderBy` filter will achieve this but you need to help it.

I would give each cat item a displayOrder since it needs something.

Then just

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in data.recipe.cat | orderBy:orderMeals">
        {{x.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

With a controller doing something like

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.data = {
        "recipe": {
          "id": "0001",
          "name": "soup",
          "cat": [{
            "name": "dinner", displayOrder: 2
          }, {
            "name": "lunch", displayOrder: 1
          }, {
            "name": "breakfast", displayOrder: 0
          }]
        }};

        $scope.orderMeals = function(item) {
          console.log('item', item);
          return item.displayOrder;
        }

});
```

Notice I added displayOrders into your recipe object ([see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xvpA5HLlz21o5i5gl8eJ?p=preview))

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     $scope.json = {
      "recipe": {
      "id":"0001",
      "name":"soup",
      "cat":[{"name":"dinner"}, {"name":"lunch"}, {"name":"breakfast"}]
      }
     };
     $scope.json.recipe.cat.reverse();
    }]);
```

.html

```
 <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
<div ng-repeat ="t in json.recipe.cat" ng-if="t.name != 'breakfast' && t.name != 'dinner'">
 here : {{t.name}}
</div>
```

see the [plunker Code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgERUbeCgroQAF8Erggg?p=preview)